# How I can use MongoDB GUI tool like mongo-express or RockMongo on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, kubernetes, kubectl, rockmongo

I have MongoDB running on Kuberenetes cluster and I am looking for a MongoDB GUI tool like PHPmyAdmin to run it as a pod on the cluster and , I have Rockmongo running as a pod but it doesn't connect to MongoDB and also I couldn't expose it, I need any microservice i can run on kubernetes cluster that can do administration for MongoDB pod that is running on default namespace as well.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rockmongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rockmongo
   replicas: 1
   template:
    metadata:
     labels:
    app: rockmongo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: rockmongo
    image: webts/rockmongo
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8050
    env:
    - name: MONGO_HOSTS
      value: '27017'
    - name: ROCKMONGO_PORT
      value: '8050'
    - name: MONGO_HIDE_SYSTEM_COLLECTIONS
      value: 'false'
    - name: MONGO_AUTH
      value: 'false'
    - name: ROCKMONGO_USER
      value: 'admin'
    - name: ROCKMONGO_PASSWORD
      value: 'admin'
```

Services running on the cluster

```
rockmongo                  ClusterIP      10.107.52.82    <none>           8050/TCP                        13s
```

Comment: Unless `rockmongo` is exposed using a loadbalancer or ingress - you won't be able to access outside of cluster (Unless you are doing port forwarding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Vishal Biyani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873601/vishal-biyani) suggested, you
may consider using [Kubernetes ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) (with [ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)) to access internal
resources of [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) or GUI for PHP operations.
Distributed databases such as MongoDB require a little extra 
attention when being deployed with orchestration frameworks such as Kubernetes.

I found interesting documentation regarding your needs of [MongoDB as a 
microservice with docker and Kubernetes](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/running-mongodb-as-a-microservice-with-docker-and-kubernetes).